# No results in an explode array

Tags: php

Basically im trying to get my PHP code to search through a txt file which has Surburbs and post codes (3000, Melbourne) etc. The user inputs a suburb and the corresponding post code is printed out.

I think almost all the way through however nothing is printing out. Not really sure why. Asked a few of my web dev friends but they were no help haha.
Any help would be greatly appreciated..
Thanks :)

```
<html>
<body>

<p>INPUT AN SUBURB NAME IN BELOW TEXT BOX AND CLICK 'SEARCH' BUTTON TO SEE 
THE RESULT.</p>

<form>
Suburb:<input type="text" name="suburb"/><input type="submit" 
value="search"/>
</form>
<?php

if(isset($_GET['suburb']))
{

//load email from file
$file = "postcode.txt";

if(!file_exists($file ))
{
    echo "No file found!";
}
else
{
    $postcodes=file($file);


    for($i=0;$i<count($postcodes);$i++)
    {
        $postcodes[$i]=str_replace("\n","",$postcodes[$i]);
        $curPostcode = explode(",", $postcodes[$i]);
        if(isset($array_postcode))
        {
            $array_postcode+=array($curPostcode[1]=>$curPostcode[0]);               
}
        else
        {
            $array_postcode=array($curPostcode[1]=>$curPostcode[0]);
        }

    }
        if(isset($array_postcode)) 
    {
        echo "nothing"
    ;}
else {

        //print_r($array_postcode);
    echo "The postcode of ".$_GET['suburb']." is : " 
.$array_postcode['suburb'];

}}


}       


?>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: print_r($postcodes) and make sure it's not empty. Also you don't need position when exploding. You do explode(" deliminator ", arrayname). Explode turns that into a string, separated by your deliminator.

Comment: @clearshot66 you have it backwards, explode turns a string into an array... implode turns an array into a string http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

Comment: My mistake :) Been awhile